# Is this drain setup legal?

Tags: plumbing

I did my own drain plumbing.
It works great and doesn't leak.

However, is this what a real plumber would do?

1. Is the 17" run (in yellow) between the elbow and the wall too long?
2. Is the jog (in blue) OK?

[The vertical drain and the elbow were off by 1" so I used 2, 22.5 degree bends to make up the inch]

[image]

Comment: It would have been better to put the elbow in the horizontal run to the stack, but it won't be a problem. I can't say if that's a legality issue, but the height of your tailpiece may be.

Comment: If I understand your comment; I thought that might add too many jogs, angles and things to glue.

Answer (score 1):

The two 22-1/2° elbows should have been in your horizontal run, moving the trap underneath and in line with the sink tailpiece. The tailpiece should remain straight. I'm not sure if this violates code, but it's unlikely to be a problem.

The length of your horizontal arm is fine. I don't know the code there, either, but it's not out of the ordinary. The maximum length partially [depends on slope](https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/plumbing/maximum-length-for-fixture-drains_o), and you don't run into any issues at 17".